# how to find the frequency of a tag or a word in r

Tags: r

Im working on stack overflow data dump .csv file and I need to to find :

The top 8 most frequent tags in the dataset.
To do this, I see the set of tags associated with each row in the ***data1.PostTypeId*** column.The frequency of a tag is equal to the number of questions that have that tag.(it means the frequency of a tag is equal to the number of rows that has that tag )

Note1 : The file is too large it has over 1 million of rows

Note2 : Im beginner in R, so I need the simplest way. My attempt is to use table function but what I got was list of tags and I couldn't figure out the top ones

This is a sample of the table Im using is below  :

Let say for example that "java" had the highest frequency (because it appeared in the most among all the rows)

then the tag "python-3.x" is the second highest frequency (because appeared the most among all the rows) 
so basically I need to go over the the second column in the table and what are the top 8 that were there

etc ...

[image]

Comment: Please provide [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269) and expected outcome

Comment: I added an example

Comment: Where? I don't see it. Please follow the link I provided you with in order to make a **reproducible** example

Comment: **reproducible** is the keyword here @user8863554

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base R with (optional) magrittr pipes for readability:

```
library(magrittr)
# Make a vector of all the tags present in data
tags_sep <- tags %>%
  strsplit("><") %>%
  unlist()
# Clean out the remaining < and >
tags_sep <- gsub("<|>", "", tags_sep)
# Frequency table sorted
tags_table <- tags_sep %>%
  table() %>%
  sort(decreasing = TRUE)
# Print the top 10 tags
tags_table[1:10]

      java             android          amazon-ec2 amazon-web-services android-mediaplayer 
          4                   2                   1                   1                   1 
      antlr              antlr4        apache-kafka              appium             asp.net 
          1                   1                   1                   1                   1
```

**Data**

```
tags <- c(
  "<java><android><selenium><appium>",
  "<java><javafx><javafx-2>",
  "<apache-kafka>",
  "<java><spring><eclipse><gradle><spring-boot>",
  "<c><stm32><led>",
  "<asp.net>",
  "<python-3.x><python-2.x>",
  "<http><server><Iocalhost><ngrok>",
  "<java><android><audio><android-mediaplayer>",
  "<antlr><antlr4>",
  "<ios><firebase><swift3><push-notification>",
  "<amazon-web-services><amazon-ec2><terraform>",
  "<xamarin.forms>",
  "<gnuplot>",
  "<rx-java><rx-android><rx-binding>",
  "<vim><vim-plugin><syntastic>",
  "<plot><quantile>",
  "<node.js><express-handlebars>",
  "<php><html>"
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly, this should solve your problem

```
library(stringr)
library(data.table)

# some dummy data
dat = data.table(id = 1:3, tags = c("<java><android><selenium>",
                                    "<java><javafx>",
                                    "<apache><android>"))

tags = apply(str_split(dat$tags, pattern = "><", simplify = T),
             2, function(x) str_replace(x, "<|>", "")) # separate one tag in each column

foo = cbind(dat[, .(id)], tags) # add the separated tags to the data
foo[foo==""] = NA # substitute empty strings with NA
foo = melt.data.table(foo, id.vars = "id") # transform to long format
foo = foo[, .N, by = value] # calculate frequency
foo[, .SD[N %in% head(N, n = 1)]] # change the value of "n" to the number you want

     value N
1:    java 2
2: android 2
3:      NA 2
```